# pandas MultiIndex square brackets, keep level names

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

What is the simplest syntax to index into a `pandas.MultiIndex` object and keep the level names?  The square bracket operator `[]` produces tuples with level names dropped.  I am looking for the cleanest way to write the last line in the code below (ideally something like `index.iloc[0]`).

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2013, 2014], [1, 2]],
                                   names=['year', 'visit'])
print(index)
print(index[0])  # tuples with level names dropped
print(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([index[0]],names=index.names))   # force reconstruct with level names
```

Produces output:

```
MultiIndex([(2013, 1),
            (2013, 2),
            (2014, 1),
            (2014, 2)],
           names=['year', 'visit'])
(2013, 1)
MultiIndex([(2013, 1)],
           names=['year', 'visit'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `slice` the MultiIndex

```py
print(index[:1])
```

```
MultiIndex([(2013, 1)],
           names=['year', 'visit'])
```

Comment: Thanks that set me on the right path.  index[[0]] works perfect.